# Is it harmless to use MUI_PAGE_WELCOME several times?

Tags: nsis

I need to show some pages that contain text at the end of my installation. As far as I can see, there is no template for just showing a text page.

Since constructing own page templates looks a bit complicated to me I thought I could just abuse `MUI_PAGE_WELCOME` for this purpose and use it multiple times, i.e. like this:

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "license.txt"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TITLE "Text page 1"
!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TEXT "An important information..." 
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TITLE "Text page 2"
!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TEXT "Another important information..." 
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TITLE "Text page 3"
!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TEXT "And a final important information..." 
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
```

This seems to work fine. Still, as someone who is rather new to NSIS I'd like to ask the question whether what I'm doing here is allowed and harmless or whether it has any implications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually use the MUI finish page (`MUI_PAGE_FINISH`) at the end but you can show the welcome page again if you really want to.

You can show any page as many times as you want. You can also create custom pages with the [nsDialogs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html) plug-in.

The MUI documentation tells you which defines apply to all pages of a certain type and which defines only applies to the next page of that type.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using `MUI_PAGE_FINISH` as well but before that I'd like to show some messages. That's why I was looking for a template page type that allows me to do that. I have seen `nsDialogs` definitions but it looks rather complicated which is why I was looking for a template. But it's good to know that I can re-use `MUI_PAGE_WELCOME` as often as I like. I guess it's just the name "Welcome" that was confusing me here because it sounds like it could only be used as the welcome page.